# Internet Explorer wants to open .PHP files

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, php

Internet Explorer is wanting to download a .php link instead of openning it and letting the server parse it. I don't have access to the webserver for editting files, but it seems any .php website forces IE to ask me to download it. I've seen this before, but I could never figure out what caused it or what fixed it. I have tried resetting Internet Explorer's settings to the defaults, clearing cookies, setting security levels to the lowest, and none of this has worked. It's currently on a Windows 7 machine, but I have seen this in Vista and XP as well, from IE6 to IE9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED. Sorry, just after I posted I remembered, the PHP links are for PDF files with special instructions, so I needed to install Adobe Reader

Comment: Luke, be sure to mark your answer as correct so people know at a glance that it's fixed.

Comment: I can't until it's been 2 days